# Collapsible accordion onClick and open handlers

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am using this: https://react-materialize.github.io/#/collapsible.

Is there a way to programmatically make a react-materialize accordion open other than clicking on it itself?

I am trying to add an onClick handler to  so that I can do a setState when one of my react-materialize collapsible accordions is selected so that I can do something based on what that state is and render content into that accordions popout (conditional rendering and for another purpose purpose.

I have 3 CollapsibleItems and this.changeBoardType is called 6 times when the page renders, if I do a setState inside it I get caught in an infinite loop:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

NOTE: the same thing happens if I use their built in onSelect prop on the `<CollapsibleItem onSelect={this.changeBoardType("single")} />`

```
<Collapsible accordion>
   <CollapsibleItem onClick={this.changeBoardType("single")} header='Single Hand' icon='filter_1'>
       <Row>
           <Input s={12}
               name="singleHand"
               type="select"
               label="Position"
               value={this.state.singleHand}
               onChange={this.handleChange}>
                              ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass an argument to an event handler such as `onClick` or `onSelect`, you need to do it like this:

```
<CollapsibleItem onClick={() => this.changeBoardType('single')} ...>
```

Calling an anonymous function that returns your `changeBoardType` function will prevent the infinite `setState` loop